# sonar.issue.enforce.multicriteria is not taken into account

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

I have set this property through the sonarQube dashboard, to a certain issue id and to a certain path (i.e. `csharpsquid:S121` => `**/*.*`).

The analysis takes place on a jenkins instance, with the SonarQube plugin (version 2.2.1). The version of the sonar-runner is 2.4. The sonarQube instance has a 5.1 version, and the database is SqlServer.

The project has a sonar-project.properties which doesn't include this property (`sonar.issue.enforce.multicriteria`). I wouldn't know how to set it, and on public forums, [the SonarSource personnel say its not possible to set this value by means of the sonar-project.properties](http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/sonar-issue-ignore-multicriteria-td5021722.html).

How can I investigate the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: What is your symptom? The *enforce* property specifies that you should *apply* the rule only to files in the specified paths. Since you've set a universal path, you might as well not have set the property at all. But at any rate, what makes you think it's not working?

Comment: The fact that the number of issues of type csharpsquid:S121 didn't decrease...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting exactly the results you've specified. I.E. you've configured that the csharpsquid:S121 rule should be applied to **/*.*, i.e. everything.

If you want to restrict its application, then you need to change your file pattern, e.g. **/particularpackage/*.*

Comment: I understand. At some point, I must have mentally replaced the section title "Restrict Scope of Coding Rules" with the category title "Exclusions".

Thanks a lot for your answer!